# How can I sign a .WLL file built in Delphi so that Microsoft Word 2013 and Word 2010 will load it?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ms-office, code-signing

My company has written a Word Add-In which is a 32 bit DLL with the file-extension ".WLL" which is a Word Add in. It is not code signed.

How do I code-sign a Win32 DLL written in Delphi such that it will be trusted by and loaded by Microsoft Office applications with their "Trust Center" settings?

I'm pretty sure I would need to buy a certificate from somebody, but I have no idea who I would buy such a certificate from.

Secondly, once I have such a certificate that is going to be accepted by Microsoft, how do I sign my Delphi executable?

(Even disabling Trust Center no longer appears to be possible, earlier versions of Office 2010 allowed it, but 14.0.6129.5000 does not)

Comment: [Here](http://delphimusings.blogspot.com/2012/03/digitally-signing-delphi-executables.html) is a fairly comprehensive discussion.

Comment: Do you really need to sign?  Excel COM add ins don't need to be signed to be loaded. Why are these different? If you need to sign, by a code signing certificate from any of the gazillion outfits that will sell you one. Note that it will take time and document exchange in order to get one. And then sign it with `signtool` from the Windows SDK.

Comment: So, certificate + signtool (download SDK).  And we're done?  I found a couple places that cell the certs on an annual basis. It seems to me I should be able to buy one that has a 10 year life at a cheap price, still looking for that...

Comment: Yes, that's all you need. We pay annually for our cert FWIW. We made our choice based on who we felt would give us the best advice and support.

Comment: Found a Root Certificate Member List at Microsoft that will tell who is qualified: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125